# Getting the above value of the currently processed array (result array during formula execution in excel)

Tags: arrays, excel, dynamic, formula

I know how to get a value from an above cell of a cell with a formula being executed but I am struggling to do the same with an array. You can simply refer to the above cell and then let the drag function of excel do the magic for the other consequence cells.

However, doing that with a dynamic array that has a single formula is new to me. I want to be able to get the above (calculated) value of a result array (currently being executed by a formula).

Take a look at the attached picture, you can see at C3 I failed to refer to the above row of the result array. The expected column in E2 is what the result should be.

[image: example data and formula]

I hope my question is clear...

Your help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this particular case merits the use of a *recursive* set-up. Simply:

`=LOOKUP(ROW(B3#),ROW(B3#)/(LEFT(B3#,4)="Ref:"),RIGHT(B3#,2))`

In any case, for the recursion you'd require a `LAMBDA`, for example:

`=LAMBDA(δ,IF(δ<1,"",IF(LEFT(INDEX($B$3#,δ),4)="Ref:",RIGHT(INDEX($B$3#,δ),2),MyLambda(δ-1))))`

stored in Name Manager as *MyLambda*, after which you can enter in the worksheet:

`=MyLambda(ROWS($1:1))`

and copy down as required.

I'm certain this `LAMBDA` could be improved, even made to spill a dynamic array, though as I said, it's really not necessary here.

Comment: I am dealing with huge data set, and I am trying to minimize the processing power, LOOKUP might not be suitable in my case. LAMBDA is not supported yet in office 360. I wonder if there is another way

Comment: I'd consider Power Query, which has a very efficient `Fill Down` feature.

Comment: I tried but it seems, mine does not support conversion of the dynamic array to power query. I only get "From Table/Range" in the sub-tab "Get & Transform Data". A clarification from you would be nice

Comment: Ah, in that case you'll have to revise your set-up so that you replicate your dynamic array within Power Query, if possible.